# Why is a UIBarButtonItem with a customView as a UIButton flashing twice when pressed? How do I stop this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to use a `UIButton` as a `UIBarButtonItem` to get some extra flexibility that isn't immediately obvious here, but necessary.

I have the following code:

```
let addButton = UIButton(type: .System)
addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(boop1(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
addButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

let addAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Add")
let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: view.tintColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
addAttributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: addAttributedString.length))

addButton.setAttributedTitle(addAttributedString, forState: .Normal)
addButton.sizeToFit()

let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: addButton)
barButtonItem.target = self
barButtonItem.action = #selector(boop2(_:))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

But when you press down, it flashes as if tapped, and then if you release it flashes again. The graphics are very peculiar.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have attached two different selectors for that `UIBarButtonItem`.

First one is here:

```
addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(boop1(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Second one is here:

```
barButtonItem.action = #selector(boop2(_:))
```

I'm not sure why you did that, but I'm sure that adding any 1 selector to the `UIBarButtonItem` will fix the issue.

Comment: I just did that for test purposes, it has no effect on stopping the flashes.